# Multiple tables drag and drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've multiple tables...Drag and drop of the rows (within a table) works fine. But how can I sort the tables itself? I need both: Sorting the rows inside a table AND sorting the tables itself.

```
<table class="sortable-table table table-bordered">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">FOO</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>TABLE 1 ROW 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TABLE 1 ROW 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="sortable-table table table-bordered">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">FOO2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>TABLE 2 ROW 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TABLE 2 ROW 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

// works fine
$( "table tbody" ).sortable({});
// ?
$( ".sortable-table" ).sortable({});
```

Answer (score 0):

If `$( "table tbody" ).sortable({});` works fine, then try this:

```
$( ".sortable-table tbody" ).sortable({}); // table
$( ".sortable-table tbody tr" ).sortable({}); // table row
```

**EDIT:**

You might want to wrap your html in a wrapper though. You can do it like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <table class="sortable-table table table-bordered">
  ...
  </table>
  <table class="sortable-table table table-bordered">
  ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Now you can sort both tables and rows like this:

```
$( ".wrapper" ).sortable( {})
$( ".sortable-table tbody tr" ).sortable({});
```

More about selectors here:

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp

https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/

You can select children elements in jQuery, just like CSS, by using `space`

Comment: Hi. That doesn't work. Drag and drop of the whole table has no effect. Just to clarify: I want both: Drag and drop of the rows inside a single table AND drag and drop of the whole table.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
I added a wrapper class

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <table class="sortable-table table table-bordered">
    ...
```

and then

```
$( ".wrapper" ).sortable( {})
```